# Strange behaviour with ng-model binding and checkbox

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to intercept a checkbox change so I can put a confirmation stage in the middle and I am experiencing strange behaviour.

When I click the checkbox `preventDefault` is stopping the UI from changing the checkbox, except the bound model will change once and then no longer be changeable.

Any ideas on how I can fix this? Am I approaching this wrong?

```
$scope.change = function(selected, $event){
      $event.preventDefault();
    };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tcVhN/197/

> edit: Answers to JB's questions below:
>
> 1. I am trying to intercept the checkbox change so I can put a confirmation step in the middle IE "Are you sure you want to change
>      this text box?"
> 2. Just updated to 1.47 (and updated jsfiddle link).
> 3. I'm using ng-click because ng-change doesn't pass the event
>      through which means I can't cancel the ui change via
>      $event.preventDefault.
> 4. See above.

Comment: Btw, you have a typo. Change `event.preventDefault()` to `$event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: 1. explain why you need to prevent default, 2. explain why you use an oooold version of angular, 3. explain why you use ng-click and not ng-change, 4. explain why you need the change function in the first place. The automatic model change should be sufficient to achieve what you want.

Comment: Hey JB added answers to you're questions to the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your Fiddle to make it work:
https://jsfiddle.net/masa671/8qrct4y2/

Notice the change in HTML: `ng-model="x.checked"` to `ng-checked="x.checked"`.

JavaScript:

```
$scope.change = function(selected, $event){
    $event.preventDefault();
    $timeout(function () {
        if (window.confirm('Are you sure?')) {
            selected.checked = !selected.checked;
        }
    });
};
```

The key problem for me was to find out, how to prevent the checkbox status from changing until the user has confirmed the change. I don't know the best/right solution, but I resolved this so that the event handler just prevents the default behaviour, and the actual change is handled outside the event handler with the help  of `$timeout`.

At least the Fiddle seems to work in a sane manner... :-)